# Polymer - document.querySelector always returning null/undefined

Tags: javascript, html, null, polymer, undefined

Here is my code:

```
<dom-module id="my-view1">
  <template id="methodScope">
    <paper-dialog id="modal1">
      <paper-swatch-picker></paper-swatch-picker>
      <paper-button dialog-confirm autofocus>Fertig</paper-button>
    </paper-dialog>
    <paper-toast id="copiedColor" text="Farbe in die Zwischenablage kopiert!"></paper-toast>
  </template>


  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-view1',
      },
      _alertColor: function(event) {
        this.selectedColor = "works";
        this.$.copiedColor.open();
      }
    });
  </script>
  <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        var t = document.querySelector('#methodScope');
        document.addEventListener('color-picker-selected', function(e) {
          t._alertColor();
        });
      });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

No matter what I try, all efforts using this.$ or document.querySelector end up in returning undefined or null, be it an element or function.

How would I be able to correctly execute the _alertColor function in the Javascript outside of the Polymer script?

Also tried it using document.querySelector('#my-view1');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, I think there is a typo in your code:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'my-view1',
  },
  _alertColor: function(event) {
    this.selectedColor = "works";
    this.$.copiedColor.open();
  }
});
```

should probably be:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'my-view1',
  _alertColor: function(event) {
    this.selectedColor = "works";
    this.$.copiedColor.open();
  }
});
```

Also: You are defining the element but you are not using it anywhere in your code. You need to create an instance of that element to be able to use its methods:

```
<!-- define the element -->
<dom-module id="my-view1">
  <template id="methodScope">
    <paper-dialog id="modal1">
      <paper-swatch-picker></paper-swatch-picker>
      <paper-button dialog-confirm autofocus>Fertig</paper-button>
    </paper-dialog>
    <paper-toast id="copiedColor" text="Farbe in die Zwischenablage kopiert!"></paper-toast>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-view1',
      _alertColor: function(event) {
        this.selectedColor = "works";
        this.$.copiedColor.open();
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<!-- use the element -->
<my-view1></my-view1>

  <script>
  HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
    var t = document.querySelector('my-view1');
    document.addEventListener('color-picker-selected', function(e) {
      t._alertColor();
    });
  });
</script>
```

In a real world application that is more complex, you want to make sure that the element has been inserted into the document.

On your website, for instance, the element is only inserted into the document when you reach the second step and click on the "Farbe in Hex".

This is what [lifecycle callbacks](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements#lifecycle-callbacks) are for, in your case most likely the "attached" callback:

```
<dom-module id="my-view1">
  <template id="methodScope">
    <paper-dialog id="modal1">
      <paper-swatch-picker id="colorpicker"></paper-swatch-picker>
      <paper-button dialog-confirm autofocus>Fertig</paper-button>
    </paper-dialog>
    <paper-toast id="copiedColor" text="Farbe in die Zwischenablage kopiert!"></paper-toast>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-view1',
      _alertColor: function(event) {
        this.selectedColor = "works";
        this.$.copiedColor.open();
      },
      attached: function() {
        //this code is running when the element is put into the DOM
        var self = this
        this.$.colorpicker.addEventListener('color-picker-selected', function() {
          self._alertColor()
        })
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: oh the first typo, happened because I cut some of the code, it is correct in my original one.

Comment: Implemented your changes, still throws an error: "my-view1.html:156 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_alertColor' of null"

Comment: Could you post a full sample that works on jsfiddle / jsbin / codepen or the like?

Comment: to fire "color-picker-selected": click the "karte" button, click continue, choose a country(doesn't matter which), continue, click on Farbe in Hex, there's the color chooser

Comment: It is my first project in polymer and a big change for me as I've been using php and plain html for the past

Comment: No worries, I'm happy to help :)

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate you helping me! :)

Your answer makes a lot of sense and should work, but I'm still getting "my-view1.html:149 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined" :/

Comment: You are missing the id "colorpicker" on line 20 in my-view1.html, see the edited answer

<paper-swatch-picker id="colorpicker"></paper-swatch-picker>

Comment: Oooh, stupid of me, thank you, really, been working on this for at least an hour before posting!

Comment: You're welcome - by the way: https://www.dpunkt.de/buecher/12286/9783864903861-web-components-mit-polymer.html ;-)

Comment: Thanks :)
Certainly tempted buying it